# SSH Remote Port Forwarding Specify Interface

Tags: ssh, openssh, ssh-tunnel, tunneling

I use this for remote port forwarding over SSH tunnel:

> ssh root@X.X.X.X -R 443:127.0.0.1:443

this binds to 0.0.0.0:443 and forwards to 127.0.0.1:443 .

The remote server has multiple IPs. Is it possible to specify the IP I want to bind to, for instance 10.10.10.1:443, instead of binding to all interfaces?

iptables is not available on the remote server.

Comment: The SSH man page says:      -R [bind_address:]port:host:hostport but it doesn't work. It ignores the bind_address and binds to all interfaces :(

Answer (score 17):

I managed to solve it.

On the remote server I set in sshd_config:

```
GatewayPorts clientspecified
```

Then I changed the arguments on the client like this:

```
ssh root@X.X.X.X -R 10.10.10.1:443:127.0.0.1:443
```

Now it works as expected, SSH binds to port 443 on interface 10.10.10.1 and forwards all traffic over the tunnel to localhost:443 .

Comment: This is helping me 7 years later :)